# Why doesn't setting ts=4 in .vimrc work?

Tags: vim

I have a stupid question but I am stuck.
I do set set ts=4 in my .vimrc file, but it looks not work. Open a new file, tab is still extended as 3 spaces. And under command mode, "set ts" got a "tabstop=3". Is there a final file like .vimrc that overwrite my ts?

Even I type :set ts=4, in vim, when I type tab, it only has 3 spaces in length.

Here is my suspicious options that cause this annoying result in my .vimrc

```
set autoindent
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set backspace=2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there something at the top or the bottom of the file like `/* vim: ts=3 */` or `// ex: set ts=3:`? Or maybe a plugin? Do you have something defined in `.vim/syntax`?

Comment: No, I searched it before asking. neither ts=3 nor tabstop=3 is in .vimrc file. And no syntax file under .vim.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
:verbose set tabstop?
```

in vim, it will tell you where the `tabstop` option value is coming from.

Comment: That's very useful command and it turned out that it was .vim/plugin/my_cscope_maps.vim that overwrote it. Thank you very much!

Comment: It also saved me a lot of time and frustration on more than one occassion :)

Comment: Wow, that's useful.  Seems like I learn something new about Vim every day.

Comment: I tried this but only got:  
    `tabstop=4`
     `Last set from ~/.vimviews/~=+voc=+app=+models=+schedule.rb=`
I still don't know where it's changed to 4 (I set it to 2 in .vimrc).

Comment: This didn't work for me either, but :version shows lots of info including the system vimrc, user vimrc & 2nd user vimrc files - check each of these.

Comment: for those who get "Last set from ~/.vim/view/.*" or something like that: remove all those files (you will lose the last view of your file but no big deal). If you keep having the problem, use `:scriptnames`